# How to get the element on clicking it's parent element

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get the specific input element on clicking on the click button. And there might be more input element with this class "quan" in the future. So, I want to get the specific input element with class "quan" on clicking the click button which associate with it. The way I did in the js file only give me the first element of that class name. How do I get the specific element? Thanks for your help.

**HTML**

```
<div>
     <div>
           <button onclick="click(event)>Click<button>
     </div>

     <div>
          <input class="quan" type="number" min="0" value="2"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    function click(event){
                                 console.log(document.querySelector(".quan"));
                          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector finding the common ancestor (using `closest`) of them and `find` the correct child.

```js
function my_click(elem) {

  // ideally elem.closest(".group-name")
  // but this will also do
  var parent = elem.parentNode.parentNode

  var child = parent.querySelector(".quan")
  console.log(child.value);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <button onclick="my_click(this)">Click</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input class="quan" type="number" min="0" value="1" />
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <div>
    <button onclick="my_click(this)">Click</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input class="quan" type="number" min="0" value="2" />
  </div>
</div>
```